# IE9 border-radius inconsistency

Tags: css

Any ideas?

I have a site with border-radius working in IE9 sometimes, but not others. I have also included the...

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

in the header. This does not seem to make a difference if present or not. It works on various parts of the page such as below...

```
#nav a {
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
padding:  8px 20px;
margin: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 1.6em;
-moz-border-radius: 1.6em;
border-radius: 1.6em;
/* text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3); */
font-size: 18px;
background-color:rgba(72,124,158,0);
    -webkit-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition:All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition:All 0.5s ease;
```

}

but not in the example below.

```
nav {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 100%;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 2em;
border-top-left-radius: 2em;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 2em;
border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
background: #007bb6; /* for non-css3 browsers */
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#004677',   endColorstr='#007bb6'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#004677), to(#007bb6)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #004677,  #007bb6); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #004677,  #007bb6); /* for Opera */
background: linear-gradient(top,  #004677,  #007bb6); 
/* border: solid 1px #6d6d6d; */    
height: 38px;
display: block;
float: right;
width: 750px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
```

I also can't see a pattern for it working or not using px or em's, or if the element uses it in conjunction with gradients or box shadows. Anybody had anything similar?

Thanks

Comment: -ms-border-radius may work :)

Comment: Simply using `border-radius` in IE9 should work fine. Make sure the DOCTYPE is HTML5.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski Doctype does not affect css3 properties.

Comment: @easwee: It affects how the effects are rendered.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - can you provide an example? I'm quite interested on it.

Comment: @easwee: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Choosing_the_right_doctype_for_your_HTML_documents

Comment: @Evan Mulawski True that it affects how the effects are rendered. But there is no relation between using a html5 doctype for rendering css3 properties. They will render the same with any other doctype. It's more about the browser triggering quirks mode or not if you ommit the doctype. If you coded your css by standards there is no difference whether you use html4 or 5 doctype - if the browser supports the property it will render the same. Only if you omit the doctype the browser will assume that you are using non-standard compliant code and it will render in it's own way.

Comment: @Evan Mulawski - I created a question here for extra feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857976/does-html5-doctype-affect-how-css3-effects-are-rendered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try without the DirectX gradient, it's overwritten my rounded corners before.

```
filter:  progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#004677',   endColorstr='#007bb6'); /* for IE */
```

Comment: +1 Tested it and after removing the filter border-radius worked as intended. Also found a nice workaround by using box-shadow to create a similar gradient looking effect: http://frugalcoder.us/post/2010/09/15/ie9-corner-plus-gradient-fail.aspx (check the edit paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

Change your padding in your .nav class to 10px, and see if it still happens.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely the linear-gradient filter that's causing the issue. A nice way around this is to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) to feature detect, and then supply different rules targeted via classes eg

```
.cssgradients {
..use the linear-gradient rules
}
.no-cssgradients {
.. another rule, not using the ie filter
}
```

In the .no-cssgradients declaration, you could supply a background image, or even cooler, a data-uri to reduce http requests eg

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA....);
```

You can translate your background images using an online tool such as [this one](http://www.abluestar.com/utilities/encode_base64/index.php)

I've used this technique to successfully combine linear gradients and rounded-corners to older ie browsers with the addition of [CSS3 PIE](http://www.css3pie.com), without CSS3 PIE then trying to also replace the linear gradient with a filter.