# Does HTML5 DOCTYPE affect how CSS3 effects are rendered?

Tags: html, css, doctype

Is there any difference how the css3 effects (for example [animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#animation)) are rendered if the doctype is defined as

`<!DOCTYPE html>` (html5)

or as let's say common

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

How do different doctypes affect css rendering (except running quirks mode that is know to render differently)?

Samples appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is almost no difference* between those two doctypes in terms of CSS rendering.

The choice of doctype only affects [validation](http://validator.w3.org/), and which "browser mode" is used out of "Quirks Mode", "Standards Mode" ("no quirks mode"), "Almost Standards Mode" ("limited quirks mode").

**See:** http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

So, `XHTML 1.0 Transitional` gives "Almost Standards Mode", whereas `<!DOCTYPE html>` gives "Standards Mode".

*One difference is a minor and easily fixable [adjustment concerning `table`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps). Another is [the treatment of heading elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6854147/405015) nested inside certain HTML5 elements.

Comment: Henri Sivonen's page was a great read - thanks for the link - the guy really got indeep with his work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that HTML5 implies in itself that the CSS improves in readibility, nothing else.

Comment: care to expand that a bit more? How exactly does it improve in readability? The syntax is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The doctype shouldn't affect this but there are libraries to help you determine what features are available to you in a particular client like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, and I can tell you that from personal experience.

[HTML pages which consist of sliced tables](http://sideproj3cts.net/wzdm) that have no cellpadding and cellspacing, fail to work with a HTML5 doctype. I had to use HTML4 transitional.

HTML pages that use grid layout systems can *sometimes* work better with a HTML5 doctype. I find that the [Tiny Fluid Grid](http://www.tinyfluidgrid.com/) does not work with a HTML4 transitional doctype.

Comment: Using tables for layout is bad practice anyway and a wrong usage of `<table>` element. I can't say much about fluid layouts - will have to check that out.

Comment: @easwee: I just tried Tiny Fluid Grid in the common browsers with a few different doctypes (including HTML4 Transitional), and it always worked for me. The table thing might be this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Comment: It's good that it works for you. About the real example I was on about, it's here. http://littersky.com With a HTML4 transitional doctype, the layout fails.

Comment: @desbest - the page does not even pass html5 validaton - no wonder it fails.

Comment: The page doesn't _pass_ validation because it uses the Shadowbox lightbox plugin which requires `rel="shadowbox[gal1]` and that sometimes made up html tag attributes are used for ajax purposes. If I took all that away the pages would pass HTML5 validation. I have validated all my pages, and the only errors there are finicky strict ones like that. Every image on that site does have an `alt=` attribute and all self closing tags end with a ` />` like the validator says.

Comment: It does thirtydot? That's weird. It didn't work when I was designing the site in 2010, testing it out in IE8, FF3/4, and Opera 10. Maybe the browsers implemented the HTML5 specification of how they handle errors or something. I'll be redesigning the site later on anyway.