# Does CSS3 work in HTML 4 Transitional?

Tags: css, html4

I am wondering if I can use CSS3 stylesheets in an html page declared as `DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"`. You know if browsers will accept this ? I know for sure that IE9 does not like the rounded corners:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

That is ignored by IE9.

Comment: Is the dtd url in your doctype?

Comment: Similar question (not duplicate) about using CSS3 between HTML5 and XHTML:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857976/does-html5-doctype-affect-how-css3-effects-are-rendered

Answer (score 1):

IE9 does support rounded corners even with the doctype transitional.
The real question here is, does browsers support CSS3, that you can find out [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html)

Comment: Not with his doctype it doesn't.