# Is HTML5 necessary for a Responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

First,im newbie to responsive design.So far from my reading about responsive design, I have
learnt ,its about

1. flexible layouts
2. media queries
3. media queries came with CSS3

But where ever i have read about responsive designs on internet HTML5 ,CSS3 and Responsive design has been spoken together.My Question is

Is HTML5 necessary for a Responsive design ?

Does HTML5 tags like header or footer tag help in anyway to make the design responsive or its all about semantics ?

What about html4 and responsive design ?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does HTML5 DOCTYPE affect how CSS3 effects are rendered?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857976/does-html5-doctype-affect-how-css3-effects-are-rendered)

Answer (score 1):

Responsive design isn't specific to web pages, but that's where you'll most commonly hear that term used. I can make a responsive design in a Windows Form application via TableLayoutPanels, that is, the form scales nicely so it looks good full screen, and when it's only 1/8 of the screen.

But really, for desktop applications, there's not as much of a need for a responsive design, since most screens for a desktop / laptop aren't smaller than 13 inches or so, especially when writing business applications.

Mobile applications / web applications (for the most part) are the only things that get accessed on a wide range of devices with varying screen sizes, which is why HTML5 and CSS get talked a lot about when discussing responsive design.

There are a lot of mobile-friendly, responsive frameworks out there for developing for the web, one of which, my personal favorite, is [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/). Using some media queries, but also defining widths as percentages of the screen, not pixels, is key in responsive design.

Hope that helps. Basically, responsive design isn't just about the web, but that's the most common place for it to be put into practice.