# How to select all elements when they have a different ID?

Tags: css

I have a CSS rule that goes like this:

```css
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstripProjectSettings-1.k-content.k-state-active,
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstripProjectSettings-2.k-content.k-state-active,
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstripProjectSettings-3.k-content.k-state-active,
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstripProjectSettings-4.k-content.k-state-active,
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div#tabstripProjectSettings-5.k-content.k-state-active 
{
    /* CSS Properties */
}
```

Is it possible to make it shorter? Because I don't know how many elements with the ID `#tabstripProjectSettings-x` will it be there.

Here's an example for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AVF3J/

Comment: Cant you use it like this ? .k-state-active {/*CSS here*/}

Comment: What Tushar means is, do you have other elements matching the class `.k-state-active` within your selector?

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try something like this:

```
div#tabstripProjectSettings.tabstrip-inner-tabstrip.k-widget.k-header.k-tabstrip div[id^="tabstripProjectSettings-"].k-content.k-state-active {
    /* css here */
}
```

The part `div[id^="tabstripProjectSettings-"]` says: select all divs whose ids start with `tabstripProjectSettings-`.
Though haven't tested it on your mega huge selector (:D), it should work. Can you bundle a fiddle though?

Answer (score 1):

Don't style them using an ID, style them using a class.

Using an id (e.g. `id="example`" in html matched with `#example` in the css) will only style elements with that specific ID. You can style multiple ID items using the sort of code you have above; there's nothing technically wrong with it.

However, if there are several elements that you want to all have the same style, a much easier way would be to give them a class. In html this means putting `class="example"` into the element, and matching it with `.example` in the css. Thereafter, every element you want to have that style, just give it that class.

You can also combine multiple classes and IDs.

Comment: While your answer sounds correct, you should elaborate a bit on your answer. Seems like the questioner doesn't know that much about CSS yet.

Comment: @SebastianZartner Does will apply if your document is CSS2?

Comment: @Schneider You can use classes and ids in all CSS - they're the fundamental basis of it.

Comment: I didint asked about ID and classes, i asked does CSS3 works if documents type is HTMl4?

Comment: CSS works independently of the HTML version a website is using. So yes, CSS3 will be interpreted within HTML4.

Comment: @Schneider ...No, you didn't.

Comment: Need to correct myself. CSS3 is mainly interpreted equally in HTML4 as in HTML5, though there may be little differences depending on whether the user agent interprets the page in [quirks mode](http://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/). See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6857976/does-html5-doctype-affect-how-css3-effects-are-rendered.